# django nonrel app engine couldn't connect to remote shell

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I have my appengine project with django nonrel. App engine SDK 1.6.6. python2.7.
I want to upload my development data to production server with 
`manage.py remote loaddata myfixture`
or simply,
`manage.py remote shell`,
but I got the url error (violation of protocol).

By the way, do I need to set django version in my app.yaml or just leave it blank and use the nonrel django?

The information is like this:

```
INFO     2012-07-03 23:34:40,720 stubs.py:79] Setting up remote_api for "xxx" at https://xxx.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
Connecting to remote_api handler.

IMPORTANT: Check your login method settings in the App Engine Dashboard if you h
ave problems logging in. Login is only supported for Google Accounts.

INFO     2012-07-03 23:34:40,884 appengine_rpc.py:466] Loaded authentication coo
kies from C:\Users\xxx/.appcfg_cookies
INFO     2012-07-03 23:34:40,885 appengine_rpc.py:160] Server: xxx.app
spot.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\git\django-project\manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\git\django-project\django\core\management\__init__.py",
line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\git\django-project\django\core\management\__init__.py",
line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\git\django-project\djangoappengine\management\commands\r
emote.py", line 15, in run_from_argv
    stub_manager.setup_remote_stubs(connection)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\git\django-project\djangoappengine\db\stubs.py", line 89
, in setup_remote_stubs
    rpc_server_factory=rpc_server_factory)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api
\remote_api_stub.py", line 682, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api
\remote_api_stub.py", line 525, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengin
e_rpc.py", line 366, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\_
_init__.py", line 367, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation
 of protocol>
```

Comment: I wonder whether or not django-nonrel is still supported:http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/goodbye

Comment: Have you tried dumpdata/loaddata locally to file?  If you have any non-serializable data it may throw an error.

Comment: yes, i had. still got this error though

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a temporally problem. It may be a due to timeout because of slow internet connection.

Comment: i guess its not. i've been tested for the whole week and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please post whole app.yaml file here.

This error seems that the problem is is app.yaml file in file path. Check all file directory in handlers. Remove '/' after the name of directory.